# Multiple Source -Multiple Destinations-No Collisions

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Lets say I have a set of destinations and another corresponding set of origins. I need to link each destination with one origin.A set of vehicles start from each origin towards their respective destination.The speed of every vehicle is provided.

In the network no two vehicles moving in opposite directions are allowed to move on a particular road at any instance of time,in brief there should not be any collisions on a road,if such a situation arrives,any one of the two vehicles which can collide on the road can wait till the other vehicle is passed or take some another path to reach its destination.

The graph can be thought of a road network where each edge in the graph represents the road and vertices in the graph can be thought of intersection of the edges.

The aim is to calculate the minimum time required for each vehicle to reach its destination and also the path taken by each vehicle to reach its destination satisfying all the above constraints.

Ideas on a way to tackle that?

Comment: can a vehicle "wait" until another vehicle has passed it's needed road?

Comment: yes ,the vehicle has both options either wait or take another path,the soul objective is to reach its destination in minimum time

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you talking about a graph were roads are paths in the graph? If no, then how do we model intersections of the roads? Even the problem to solve is not quite clear. Are we supposed to find the path that each vehicle has to take?  Or something else?

Comment: yes ,the roads are paths in the graph and we need to find the path of each vehicle will take to reach its destination in minimal time satisfying all the constraints

Comment: i have made the changes in the question ,please suggest some ideas to tackle the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is NP-hard.

The problem of deciding whether all cars can complete their trips in at most some given number k of time units is NP-hard, even under any combination of the following simultaneous restrictions: all cars travel at unit speed, every edge has length 1, k = 3.  A problem being NP-hard means there's almost certainly no polynomial-time algorithm that solves every instance.  To show this I'll give a reduction from the NP-hard problem [3SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability): In this problem, we are given a Boolean expression in the form of a conjunction (AND) of n clauses, each of which is a disjunction (OR) of 3 literals, each of which is either a variable or its negation (NOT).  There are m variables overall, each of which we can assign to either TRUE or FALSE; our task is to determine whether the overall expression is *satisfiable* -- that is, whether there exists any assignment of TRUE or FALSE values to the m variables that causes the overall expression to be TRUE.

### Constructing an instance of your problem from an arbitrary 3SAT instance

Suppose we have an instance of 3SAT with n clauses and m variables.  We can construct an instance of your problem in which each variable becomes an edge, with the direction of traffic (left-to-right or right-to-left) along that edge corresponding to the value (TRUE or FALSE) of the variable.  Each clause becomes a gadget that connects to both ends of 3 of these variable-edges.  Intuitively, each clause-gadget gives a vehicle starting at its start point (think of this as being on the left) one of 3 options to reach its corresponding end point (think of this as being on the right).  Specifically:

- First, delete any clause that contains both a variable and its negation as literals.  This serves to remove length-2 trips from the graph without affecting satisfiability of the original expression, since such a clause is satisfiable by *any* assignment.
- For each variable x_i, create two vertices u_i and v_i, and the edge (u_i, v_i).  All edges in this construction have weight (distance?) 1.
- For all 1 <= j <= n, build a gadget corresponding to the jth clause as follows: Create a vertex s_j and a vertex t_j.  Let the literals in the jth clause be a, b and c.  Let x_i be the variable in literal a.  If a is a positive literal, create the edges (s_j, u_i) and (v_i, t_j), otherwise (i.e., if it equals "NOT x_i") create the edges (s_j, v_i) and (u_i, t_j).  Do likewise for literals b and c.
- Finally, add (s_j, t_j) as a (source, destination) pair for each 1 <= j <= n.  Give each such car unit speed.

I now claim that the original 3SAT instance is satisfiable if and only if the just-constructed instance of your problem has a solution with duration at most 3.

### YES to 3SAT instance => YES to instance of your problem

First I'll show that if the 3SAT instance is satisfiable, then there exists a solution to the just-constructed instance of your problem with duration 3.  In this case we can assume that a satisfying assignment Y exists, so for every 1 <= i <= m let y_i be the assignment to variable x_i in some such satisfying assignment.  Now in the just-constructed instance, orient every edge incident on some s_j away from s_j, every edge incident on some t_j toward t_j, and each variable-edge as follows: If y_i = TRUE, then orient the edge (u_i, v_i) from u_i to v_i, while OTOH if y_i = FALSE, orient the edge from v_i to u_i.  Since by assumption Y is a satisfying assignment, we know that every clause contains at least 1 literal that evaluates to TRUE: that is, in each clause there is at least 1 literal z containing a variable x_i such that either z is positive and x_i = TRUE, or z is negative and x_i = FALSE.  This implies that, for every clause j, there is at least 1 path from s_j to t_j that agrees with the orientation of edges established above.  Clearly, if cars only ever travel across edges in the direction given by the orientation above, there can never be two cars crossing an edge in opposite directions, so such car trips do not interfere with each other.  Since these paths from s_j to t_j all have length 3 and no trips interfere with each other, all trips can be simultaneously completed in 3 time steps.

### YES to instance of your problem => YES to 3SAT instance

Now I'll show that if the solution to the just-constructed instance of your problem has duration at most 3, then there exists a satisfying assignment to the original 3SAT instance.  Assume that there is such a solution to the just-constructed instance: then clearly, every trip must be completed in at most 3 time units.  For a car to get from s_j to t_j, it must use at least 1 of the 3 edges incident on s_j, and at least 1 of the 3 edges incident on t_j, so it must take at least 2 time units; furthermore, because we deleted any clauses containing both a variable and its negation, no vertex is adjacent to both an s_j and t_j for any j, so at least one more edge is required, meaning 3 time units is the shortest path we could hope for (since every edge takes 1 time unit).  So every trip in the solution must take exactly 3 time units, along a 3-edge path that experiences no hold-ups due to cars coming the other way.  Notice that the middle leg on such a path must be a single variable-edge, since the only other ways of getting from some u_i to v_i or vice versa involve "doubling back" via at least 2 more edges.  In particular, for the trip starting at s_j, it must be one of the 3 distinct variable-edges corresponding to the 3 literals in clause j.  Specifically, let the literals in the jth clause be a, b and c.  Let x_i be the variable in literal a.  If a is positive, then "from u_i to v_i" is one of the 3 permitted legs for the trip starting at s_j, otherwise (i.e., if a is negative) "from v_i to u_i" is.  Likewise for the remaining literals b and c.  So, thus far, we have established that:

- For each 1 <= j <= n, a car can travel from s_j to t_j in at most 3 time units using one of the 3 middle legs corresponding to the literals in clause j.

We build a solution to the 3SAT instance as follows: For each variable x_i, if the edge (u_i, v_i) is crossed by one or more cars from u_i to v_i, assign TRUE to y_i; if it is crossed by one or more cars from v_i to u_i, assign FALSE to y_i; otherwise (if the edge is not crossed at all), arbitrarily assign either value to y_i.  We need to show two things: that no variable is assigned both TRUE and FALSE, and that the assignment causes the expression to take the value TRUE.

First, the only condition under which a variable x_i could be assigned both TRUE and FALSE by the above rule is if at least one car traverses the edge (u_i, v_i) in each direction.  Suppose towards contradiction that this is true: some variable-edge (u_i, v_i) is crossed in opposite directions by 2 different car trips in the solution.  Then clearly at least one of the two cars must pause for at least 1 time step to let the other one through this edge.  But then the solution would need at least 4 time steps, contradicting our assumption of a solution of duration at most 3 time steps, thus it must be that if any cars cross edge (u_i, v_i), then they all do so in the same direction, and thus each variable is assigned at most one of TRUE or FALSE.

Second, for each 1 <= j <= n, we can reinterpret the jth clause of the 3SAT instance as "A car can travel from s_j to t_j in at most 3 time units using one of the middle legs corresponding to the literals in clause j", where "corresponding" is used in the same sense as earlier.  Observe that under this interpretation, the 3SAT instance is (a) equivalent to the statement in the bullet point above, which we have already established to be TRUE, and (b) still formally equivalent to the original 3SAT problem (since all we have done is given an interpretation to its variables and clauses).

It follows that the variable assignment for the 3SAT problem that we just built from the solution to the instance of your problem is free of contradictions and produces the value TRUE: i.e., the 3SAT formula is satisfiable.

### Wrapping up

We have now established that a YES answer to the question "Does there exist a satisfying assignment for this 3SAT expression?" implies a YES answer to the question "Does there exist a way of getting all cars from their starting points to their destinations in 3 time steps or less?", and also that a YES answer to the latter question implies a YES answer to the former.  Thus a NO answer to either question also implies a NO answer to the other: that is, the questions are equivalent.  We constructed the instance of your problem in polynomial time from the given 3SAT instance, so if there was some algorithm that could solve your problem in polynomial time, it could also be used to solve *any* 3SAT instance in polynomial time -- by first constructing such an instance of your problem, calling this algorithm to solve that instance as a subroutine, and then returning the answer.  Thus your problem is at least as hard as 3SAT, namely NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: any ideas for an approximation algorithm for this problem

Comment: Here's an easy 2-approximation algorithm (that is, an algorithm that guarantees to produce a solution that is no worse than 2 times the duration of an optimal solution):  1. For each car, calculate the shortest path from its source to its destination.  2. Choose an arbitrary initial orientation for each edge.  Every edge's orientation will be flipped after each time step.  3. Move each car from its source to its destination at a rate of 1 edge every 2 time steps, in each 2-time-step block choosing to move during the edge orientation that agrees with the direction of travel.

Comment: This is 2-optimal because just driving each car along its shortest path takes exactly half the time, and nothing could be shorter than doing that.  Note that, if after step 1 it happens that no 2 shortest paths need to traverse the same edge at the same time in opposite directions then you can stop -- that solution is optimal :)

Comment: Thanks once again :)

Comment: any ideas if the edge length is not one but every edge is of some integer length.This approximation will be then according to the length of the edges?

Comment: The approximation I described above will then be a 2L-approximation, where L is the length of the longest edge.

Comment: any ideas on using this model in networking by dividing the packets and sending them across different paths to reduce the delay of packets reaching their destinations.

Comment: Well, it accomplishes that goal, but presumably existing networking algorithms do so too?  And probably better.  You probably need a way to somehow distribute information about changes in the network topology either to all nodes, or to "enough" nodes.

Comment: some cars in this model will need to wait for long amount of time due to some cars travelling on longer path,any ideas if the cars are given priority according to the distance left to reach their destination and edge orientation are reversed according to the priority ,will it help to optimize ?

Comment: Sometimes, probably.

Comment: Ideas on how to make the general algorithm with including the priority factor for the vehicles

Comment: I'm out of ideas to help you; try coming up with your own.

Comment: What if the car instead of waiting , take some another path which will take less time than the shortest path ,will the time taken less the than the previous algorithm

Comment: Try it and see. Look, the problem is NP-hard, so no simple heuristic will give the best answer on every input; maybe some simple heuristic will always give an answer within some multiplicative bound better than the bound of 2 that I gave, but finding such a heuristic and proving that this holds for it is (A) a lot of work and (B) probably impossible, or at least research-level computer science. I'm not prepared to invest that kind of time and effort on your behalf; either do it yourself, or be satisfied with the best answer that remains available: probably such heuristics will sometimes help.

Comment: To see why your comment "What if the car instead of waiting..." isn't very helpful: yes, *of course*, if there's another path free for that car then *obviously* taking that path will lead to a faster solution overall; the problem is what to do when there are *multiple* cars that would like to use that path.  What then?  You don't say.  So: Try some ideas like that out, discover the remaining problems that need to be worked out (like the one I just mentioned in this comment), try some ideas to fix those (e.g. randomly pick a car), see what works well on a large set of example problems, iterate.